# Add a file of strings into an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to add this file into an arraylist which I will later compare to another arraylist. So far I have this but it is giving me a compiling error. It is saying that it cannot find the symbol .hasNext and . readLine.

```
ArrayList<String> america = new ArrayList<String>();
    while((infile2.hasNext()))
    {
        america.add(infile2.nextLine());
    }
```

Can someone help me figure out how to fix these errors?

Comment: At a guess you're `infile2` is probably something like a `BufferedReader` when it should be a `Scanner`

Comment: What kind of object/class is infile2?

Comment: Yes it is a bufferedReader but my teacher says not to change it. So I can't make it into a scanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes it is a bufferedReader

`BufferedReader` doesnt have a `hasNext` method, therefore you can use `readLine`

```
String line;
while((line = infile2.readLine()) != null) {
    americaList.add(line);
}
...
```

Or if you could use `Files`

```
List<String> americaList = 
         Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("list.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way to do it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner(new File("INPUT_FILE_NAME"));
```

Then, change your loop to use `hasNextLine()` instead of `hasNext()`. 
For Java's `Scanner` you should always pair the `has` with the corresponding type of `next`.

You can **wrap** the `BufferedReader` that someone hands you inside a Scanner.

```
 Scanner inFile = new Scanner(myBufferedReader);
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the BufferedReader file into a scanner.... Is there another way?

Comment: @Ayoshna, See the update and let me know whether you are allowed to wrap it.

Comment: Nope. He has given us this line and we are not allowed to change his work. This is what it says: BufferedReader infile2 = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("allPresidents.txt") );

Comment: @Ayoshna, Can you add a line **below** it, that says `Scanner infile3 = new Scanner(infile2);`? That does not change his original line.

Answer (score 0):

```
       /**
 * one time read all
 * 
 * @param location
 * @return
 */
public static List<String> readLine(String location){
    BufferedReader is = null;
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        is = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(location))); 
        String line = null;
        while((line = is.readLine())!=null){
            result.add(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw Exceptions.unchecked(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw Exceptions.unchecked(e);
    } finally{
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw Exceptions.unchecked(e);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions. I think BufferedReader will be better.

Comment: Can you explain the line where you assigned is. What do you mean by location?

Comment: location is the file's path, example c:\\a.txt